# How to find all image uris in a text using python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to get img uris in a text like this:

```
    hello bla

    <br> <img src="/media/photos/1084/PBWHFH7J1rzhr63o1_400.gif" class="someclass" />
    some blablabla 
    <br> <img src="/media/photos/344/tgrfgregfwe_540.jpg" class="otherclass" /> 
    </br>
   more blabla
```

So the result should be:

```
['/media/photos/1084/PBWHFH7J1rzhr63o1_400.gif', '/media/photos/344/tgrfgregfwe_540.jpg']
```

Comment: have a look at `pydoc re`

Comment: I tried `print re.findall('url\(([^)]+)\)',mystring)`, but it returned nothing.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin yes, but I could not come up with a solution.

Comment: @Jand that is because your regex does not make sense. Maybe start by learning regular expressions properly, or avoiding them and using HtmlParser - https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>>> for i in soup.find_all('img'):
...     print(i.get('src'))
...     
... 
/media/photos/1084/PBWHFH7J1rzhr63o1_400.gif
/media/photos/344/tgrfgregfwe_540.jpg

>>> [i.get('src') for i in soup.find_all('img')]
['/media/photos/1084/PBWHFH7J1rzhr63o1_400.gif', '/media/photos/344/tgrfgregfwe_
540.jpg']
>>>
```

Comment: Great! Just get this warning: 'To get rid of this warning, change this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "html.parser")' waring. Also please add the import .

Comment: @Jand: As the warning said, just use `BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")` instead of `BeautifulSoup(html)`. Check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

we have xml parser to make things easy for us.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
image = "<img src='/media/photos/1084/PBWHFH7J1rzhr63o1_400.gif' class='someclass' />"
xml_object = minidom.parseString(image)
image_tags = image_xml.getElementsByTagName('img')
list_of_srcs = []
for image_tag in image_tags:
    list_of_srcs.append(image_tag.getAttributeNode('src').value)
print list_of_srcs
```

Comment: really? why not use HtmlParser instead ;) - https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html

Comment: yes we can use HTMLParser , this is one way to do it.

Comment: my point is - html is not necessarily also well-formed xml, which means the xml parser solution may fail on some inputs (depending on the robustness of the parser, which I am not familiar with.)

Comment: @saikumarm I deal with irregular texts. So I tried your answer with some characters inserted before `<img` and got `NameError: name 'image_tags' is not defined` error. So this seems too restrictive for my case. Thanks anyway.